# Passing a hash to a controller in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, hash

Using Geocoder gem, i have a helper method that can show current location. I would like to show users events that belong to their home country and nothing else. I can't figure out how to pass the info to the controller.

**Helper**

```
def myplace
     @myplace = request.location.country
end
```

**Print/Show**

```
<%= myplace %>
```

I am trying to pass ***myplace*** to the controller

**Controller**

```
@events = Event.where('start_at > ?', Time.zone.now).where(country: params[:myplace]).order('end_at ASC').limit(4)
```

Can you please explain to me how i can query events based on user's locale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your controller has access to the request, so you could:

```
@events = Event.where('start_at > ?', Time.zone.now).where(country: request.location.country).order('end_at ASC').limit(4)
```

Comment: I don't know why i was going the long way.. Thanks mate

Answer (score 3):

If you want a method to be available to both your views and controllers, it doesn't go in your helper files. You need to put it in your controller, and make it available as a helper to your views with `helper_method`:

```
class MyController

  helper_method :myplace


  def my_action
    @events = Event.where('start_at > ?', Time.zone.now)
      .where(country: myplace)
      .order('end_at ASC').limit(4)
  end

  protected

  def myplace
    @myplace = request.location.country
  end
end
```